# How to determine if OnsenUI component is compiled in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, onsen-ui

My project is built with [vue-cordova-webpack template](https://github.com/OnsenUI/vue-cordova-webpack). I created a vue-component. There is `v-ons-input` inside the template of my component. I need to change the value of `v-ons-input` during the unit test of my component. I can do it only after `ons-input` is compiled, because only after compilation `ons-input` has `input` inside (see about [OnsenUI component compilation](https://onsen.io/v2/guide/compilation.html#components-compilation)). The problem is a compilation is executed asynchronously and I didn't find any "legit" way to catch the event when OnsenUI component is ready for use.

What do I do? I created a sinon spy for an internal method `_compile` of the `ons-input` and wait until it's been called:

```
it('test', (done) => {
   const wrapper = mount(myVueComponent)

   // here I can't set a value for ons-input

   var spy = sinon.spy(wrapper.find('ons-input').element, '_compile')

   function waitForCall(spy) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       (function wait() {
         if (spy.called) {
           return resolve()
         }
         setTimeout(wait, 10)
       })()
     })
   }

   waitForCall(spy).then(function () {
     // now ons-input is compiled and I can set a value for ons-input
     wrapper.find('ons-input').element.value = 'foo'
     ...
   }).then(done, done)
 })
```

Is there more "clean" way to determine that OnsenUI component is ready for use in a unit test (without manipulation with internal methods of the component)?

P.S. I know the way not for test environment - listening for `init` event for `document`(see [here](https://community.onsen.io/topic/1159/component-not-ready-in-ons-ready/6)), but  it doesn't work in unit tests.

Comment: As per [the docs](https://onsen.io/v2/api/vue/v-ons-input.html) `v-ons-input` is supposed to work almost exactly the same as a normal `input` tag. In which case I think you should just stub it out since you're supposed to be testing *your* component, not `v-ons-input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` should be as good as anything here.

```js
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('ons-input input'));
```

##### Internal details (can be skipped)

The file defining `VOnsInput` [imports](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/04eb575ebfbc10eb53db1b0cc47cf1f7d789a293/bindings/vue/src/components/VOnsInput.vue#L9https://) `ons-input`, which registers `ons-input` as a Custom Element. This happens synchronously so as long as the Vue component's script has been executed, it is guaranteed that `ons-input` will be registered as a Custom Element.

During registration of `ons-input`, Onsen UI uses a function `contentReady` to wait for compilation to be finished, but that function is not part of the public API. However, `contentReady` uses `setTimeout` (technically `setImmediate` but it amounts to the same thing) [as a fallback](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/04eb575ebfbc10eb53db1b0cc47cf1f7d789a293/core/src/ons/content-ready.js#L63) so by using `setTimeout` once you are effectively doing the same thing.

In short, this means that using `setTimeout` should guarantee that the inner `input` is attached when `setTimeout`'s callback is run.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just wanted to add that I wrapped setTimeout in promise `function wait () { return new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(resolve)})}` because it's more convenient to use it in `async` test. Just call `await wait()` and then find `ons-input` and make assertions.